# Calling returning value from select statement

Tags: postgresql, insert, postgis

I need to insert a polygon into a postgresql table "polygontable" and then return its (the_geom) value for further querying. I want to be grabbing the most recently inserted instance in "polygontable". How do I call the returned "polygongeom" in a SELECT statement?

```
INSERT INTO polygontable (the_geom) 
VALUES (ST_SetSRID((ST_MakeValid(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON('"+JSON.stringify(payload)+"'))),4326)) returning the_geom as polygon_geom;  

SELECT st_intersects(polygon_geom, other_table.the_geom) 
from polygon_geom, other_table;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are on 9.1 you can do something like this:

```
with inserted as 
(
  insert into ... 
  returning the_geom as new_geom
)
SELECT st_intersects(inserted.new_geom, other_table.the_geom) 
from inserted, other_table;
```